# Issue with printing space with single quotes in a int array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, character-encoding, output

I want to print my `int[]` in a specific format (within `space` between each numbers, etc)

However I found Java does not print the spaces in the single quotes, and it even change my numbers in the `int[]`. Same things happened to the `bracket` character.

For example:

```
    int[] test = {1,2,3,4,5};

    System.out.println('(' + test[0]+ ' ' +test[1] + ' ' + test[2] + ' ' 
            +test[3] + ' ' + test[4] + ')');

    //224

    System.out.println("(" + test[0]+ " " +test[1] + " " + test[2] + " " 
            +test[3] + " " + test[4] + ")");

    //(1 2 3 4 5)
```

I think `space` and `bracket` are characters, and I wonder why I need to use `double quotes` to print them properly and why the `single quotes` with `space` character would change the output?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, characters are fundamentally stored as numbers. When you add characters together with other numbers, you'll receive a number as a result.

```
// Prints 97
System.out.println('a' + 0);
```

The only situation where characters will *not* be added as a number is when they're added to a string.

```
System.out.println("Letter" + 'a');
```

In your code above, you only add numbers and characters together, so you get a number as output. Java adds things from left to right, so by changing the first-appearing character to a string, you should get your desired output.

```
// Fixed version
System.out.println("(" + test[0]+ ' ' +test[1] + ' ' + test[2] + ' ' 
        +test[3] + ' ' + test[4] + ')');
```

Answer (score 3):

Quoting with apostrophes is a `char` literal. A `char` is a numeric primitive, and can be added to other numeric primitives like `int`.

The `+` operator is also overloaded to implement string concatenation. If either side of the operator is a `String`, the `+` operator is a string concatenation operator, otherwise it is a numeric add operator.

So, `'A' + 5` means add 5 to the numeric value of character `A`, while `"A" + 5` means concatenate the string `A` with the string representation of the number `5`.

In your case, it would have been enough to change the first character into a `String` literal. All the remaining `+` operators would then become string concatenation operators:

```
System.out.println("(" + test[0] + ' ' + test[1] + ' ' + test[2] + ' ' 
        + test[3] + ' ' + test[4] + ')');

//(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Single quoting in Java means a char type, whereas the double-quote means a String type.  So your first line is trying to print the values of those chars.  See here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println() for the overloaded methods.